# Primary key and Foreign key query

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.I want to display the name of customer who ordered for the item no 100 and 105. If they ordered both the items then display customer name once.

Table 1:Customer and their attribute Cus_name(it is primary key)

Table 2:Items  and their attribute Item_no(it is primary key)

Table 3:Orders and their attribute Cus_name(it is foreign key),Item_no(it is foreign key)

I tried partially and i got error.

```
SELECT Cus_name 
FROM Orders
WHERE Item_no='100' and Item_no='105';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from orders,use some post aggregate filtering to get names with both orders

```
SELECT Cus_name 
FROM Orders
GROUP BY Cus_name 
HAVING SUM(Item_no='100')>0
 and SUM(Item_no='105')>0;
```